How to find a fit for the following data?
Consider the following function:
AvalFD[T_, x_] = 
  Integrate[x^2/(Exp[x/T] + 1), {x, 0, Infinity}, 
    Assumptions -> T > 0] // N;
DistrFD[T_, x_] = 1/AvalFD[T, x]*x^2/(Exp[x/T] + 1);
ICDFa[p_] := 
 Evaluate[
  InverseFunction[(Function @@ {x, 
       Integrate[DistrFD[1, xi], {xi, 0, x}, Assumptions :> x > 0]})][
   p]]

It is an inverse CDF $\text{CDF}^{-1}(u), 0<u<1$ for the distribution $\propto x^{2}/(\exp[-x/T]+1)$, where $T$ is a real parameter and $0<x<\infty$ (see also this question). I would like to find a fit for this function. Generically, I split the interval u into several pieces. However, I do not want to split the interval into many pieces since I will use the fit to sample a single point a billion times, and any performance decrease is crucial.
I cannot manage Mathematica to find the adequate fit automatically, so instead I have found it manually:
formulafit[x_] = 
 x^0.6 (1 + 5.3 x)/(1 - 0.9 x)
   Exp[0.15/(1 - x)^0.2] Sqrt[(1 - 0.9 x)]/x^1.5
formulafit[x_] = formulafit[x]/formulafit[0.79] ICDFa[0.79];
formulafit1[x_] = Exp[0.25/(1 - 0.99 x)^0.33];
formulafit1[x_] = formulafit1[x]/formulafit1[0.9745] ICDFa[0.9745];
formulafit2[x_] = Exp[0.3/(1 - 0.9989 x)^0.195]/(1 - 0.6 x)^0.13;
formulafit2[x_] = formulafit2[x]/formulafit2[0.995] ICDFa[0.995];
formulafit3[x_] = Exp[0.3/(1 - 0.9992 x)^0.20]/(1 - 0.96 x)^0.9;
formulafit3[x_] = formulafit3[x]/formulafit3[0.999] ICDFa[0.999];
fitfinal[x_] = 
  Piecewise[{{2.24 x^0.334 (1 + 100 x), 
     x < 10^-5}, {2.2942 x^0.336 (1 + 13 x), 
     10^-5. <= x < 0.7*10^-3}, {2.469 (
      x^0.345 (1 + 1.3 x))/(1 + 1.9 x^2), 
     0.7*10^-3 <= x < 0.115}, {3.08 x^0.41 (1 + 0.3*x), 
     0.115 <= x < 0.2}, {2.1695 x^0.273 (1 + 0.62*x)/(1 - 0.345*x), 
     0.2 <= x < 0.59}, {1.76 x^0.1 (1 + 0.42*x)/(1 - 0.6*x), 
     0.59 <= x < 0.79}, {formulafit[x], 
     0.79 <= x < 0.9745}, {formulafit1[x], 
     0.9745 <= x < 0.995}, {formulafit2[x], 
     0.995 <= x < 0.999}, {formulafit3[x], 0.999 <= x}}];
ptsinterpolation = 
  Join[Table[10^x, {x, -9., -1., 0.1}], 
   Table[x, {x, 0.103, 0.99, 0.001}], 
   Table[x, {x, 0.991, 0.999, 0.001}], {0.9991, 0.9992, 0.9993, 
    0.9994, 0.9995, 0.9996, 0.9997, 0.9998, 0.9999, 1.}];
tabdeviation = 
  ParallelTable[{pt, (fitfinal[pt]/ICDFa[pt] - 1) 100}, {pt, 
    ptsinterpolation}];

Typically, the departure tabdeviation from 0 is tiny, but the situation becomes more complex in the domain of high values of x, where I can't find the accurate enough fit.
Could you please tell me how to find the fit for large values of u (0.995 < u < 1), possibly using some built-in Mathematica features?
P.S. Using InverseFunction to the analytic PDF would be very slow:
CDFval[x_] = Integrate[DistrFD[1, X], {X, 0, x}, Assumptions -> x > 0];
InvCDFval[u_] := 
 Evaluate[InverseFunction[(Function @@ {x, CDFval[x]})][u]]
InvCDFval[0.3] // AbsoluteTiming


{0.0008149, 2.07493}

In contrast, the sampling using fitfinal is very fast, but inaccurate for large us:
FastFDsampler = 
 Hold@Compile[{{u, _Real}, {T, _Real}}, T*fitfinal[u], 
     CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", 
     RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}] /. ruleDown[{fitfinal}] // 
  ReleaseHold
pts1 = FastFDsampler[RandomReal[{0, 1}, 10000], 3]; // RepeatedTiming


{0.000741296,Null}


Why do you need a fit, though? Your cdf can be analytically calculated as $$\operatorname{cdf}(x)=\frac{4 x \text{Li}_2\left(-e^{-x}\right)+4 \text{Li}_3\left(-e^{-x}\right)-2 x^2 \log \left(e^{-x}+1\right)+3 \zeta (3)}{3 \zeta (3)},$$ so you just use InverseFunction on this (or NSolve or whatever) to get the inverse ...

@Domen : as far as I understand, it would be very slow. Say, sampling 10^3 points would be as long as 1 second (see the cited question), while I need many orders of magnitude faster evaluation.

Your link points to this same question ...

@Domen : I apologize, fixed.

@JohnTaylor Since you need 1000x speed at ANY cost, Since a plot of @Domen`s cdf looks similar to a sigmoid with some distortion for x, Since the inverse of a sigmoid is a logistic, is there ANY chance you could manually tweak the form of the logistic equation, it looks like you may maybe tweaked the form of the sigmoid to get what you have, to get a good fit without needing Piecewise? That tweaked logistic might be fast enough for you, if not then maybe c compiling that would be, if that isn't fast enough then maybe having a GPU calculate that would be fast enough. Please let us know.
